# Cannot connect remotely to the docker mysql container

Tags: mysql, docker

I have setup docker for my mysql and spring-boot application. My application works fine, and also connects to the MySQL container. But I am not able to access my MySQL container through MySQL Workbench (or any other client) remotely.

Each time I try to connect to the MySQL Container remotely, I receive an error saying

`ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0`

Although, I can access my MySQL container through docker bash. It's just that I cannot access it remotely.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '2.1'
services:
  my-mysql:
   container_name: my-mysql
   image: mysql/mysql-server:5.7
   environment:
    MYSQL_DATABASE: test_database
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
   ports:
    - '3301:3301'
   expose:
    - '3301'
   restart: always

  my-app:
    image: my-app
    build:
      context: ./spring-boot-app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8087:8080
    volumes:
      - /data/spring-boot-app
    depends_on:
      my-mysql:
         condition: service_healthy
```

In short, everything works fine, my application, my mysql container. It's just that I cannot access my MySQL Container remotely.

Note that I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: Safeer , just a nit pick query : default on mysql is 3306. Should you not forward 3301 -> 3306 (assuming you use docker:3301 in jdbc driver url - looking at spring boot in the yaml)  ->    - '3301:3301' to     - '3301:3306'
Change the yaml to

Comment: do not use `mysql:5.7` if there is no specifi dependecny, use `mysql:8`. second thing you should bind port `3306` mysql workbench this port as a default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you @ramachandran-a-g for helping me out. :)

It was a small stupid mistake that I had been doing.

Replacing `3301:3301` with `3301:3306` solved the issue.

I am able to access my MySQL container remotely now.